# Nipplejs Direction event Trigger Interval

Tags: javascript

I've been trying to implement a joystick in my js html nodejs based online game **the problem is** the movement triggers when direction changes but nipplejs triggers direction event too fast and **slowing the player from the server is not an option** for the sake of slow internet connection is there is anyway i can set the direction event trigger timeout in nipplejs?[joystick touch for about half a second example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nr21u.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

If you're receiving player input too often and can't slow it on the server, why not slow it on the client?

There are 2 solutions to your problem that I immediately think of:

- Rewrite your game so **you** make the interval. User input just updates a direction variable which your interval loops from. *This also means that you don't have to worry about input events triggering too slow.*
- Add a (client-side) debounce to the input events. I.e. ignore (duplicate) events that you already saw less than X milliseconds ago.